# Get current scroll position of ScrollView in React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

Is it possible to get the current scroll position, or the current page of a `<ScrollView>` component in React Native?

So something like:

```
<ScrollView
  horizontal={true}
  pagingEnabled={true}
  onScrollAnimationEnd={() => { 
      // get this scrollview's current page or x/y scroll position
  }}>
  this.state.data.map(function(e, i) { 
      <ImageCt key={i}></ImageCt> 
  })
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Relevant: [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2215) suggesting adding a convenient way of getting this information.

Answer (score 280, accepted):

Try.

```
<ScrollView onScroll={this.handleScroll} />
```

And then:

```
handleScroll: function(event: Object) {
 console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
},
```

In another context, let's say you also want to implement a pagination
indicator, you'll want to go further by doing this:

```
<ScrollView
     onScroll={Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: 
     scrollX } } }], {listener: (event) => handleScroll(event)})}
     scrollEventThrottle={16}
>
   ...some content
</ScrollView>
```

where scrollX would be an animated value you can use for you pagination and your handleScroll function can take the form:

```
  const handleScroll = (event) => {
    const positionX = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
    const positionY = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
  };
```

Comment: This won't always fire when the scroll value changes. If for example scrollview is resized causing it to now be able to display the whole thing on screen at once you don't always seem to get an onScroll event telling you.

Comment: Or `event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x` if you've got a horizontal ScrollView ;) Thanks!

Comment: This also we can use in Android.

Comment: Frustratingly, unless you set [`scrollEventThrottle`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrolleventthrottle) to 16 or lower (to get an event for every single frame), there's no guarantee that this will report the offset on the *final* frame - meaning that to be sure that you have the right offset after scrolling has finished, you need to set `scrollEventThrottle={16}` and accept the performance impact of that.

Comment: @bradoyler: is it possible to know the maximum value of `event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y`?

Comment: I am getting an error: Property 'nativeEvent' does not exist on type 'Object'

Comment: I use it with `onLayout` listener to make sure that both the page size and the page offset are in my hands so that I can make the scrollview usable. BTW, unless I add the `scrollEventThrottle` property, the RN runtime will warn about it.

Answer (score 82):

Disclaimer: what follows is primarily the result of my own experimentation in React Native 0.50. The [`ScrollView` documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html) is currently missing a lot of the information covered below; for instance `onScrollEndDrag` is completely undocumented. Since everything here relies upon undocumented behaviour, I can unfortunately make no promises that this information will remain correct a year or even a month from now.

Also, everything below assumes a purely vertical scrollview whose *y* offset we are interested in; translating to *x* offsets, if needed, is hopefully an easy exercise for the reader.

---

Various event handlers on a `ScrollView` take an `event` and let you get the current scroll position via `event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y`. Some of these handlers have slightly different behaviour between Android and iOS, as detailed below.

### [`onScroll`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#onscroll)

#### On Android

Fires every frame while the user is scrolling, on every frame while the scroll view is gliding after the user releases it, on the final frame when the scroll view comes to rest, and also whenever the scroll view's offset changes as a result of its frame changing (e.g. due to rotation from landscape to portrait).

#### On iOS

Fires while the user is dragging or while the scroll view is gliding, at some frequency determined by [`scrollEventThrottle`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrolleventthrottle) and at most once per frame when `scrollEventThrottle={16}`. *If* the user releases the scroll view while it has enough momentum to glide, the `onScroll` handler will also fire when it comes to rest after gliding. However, if the user drags and then releases the scroll view while it is stationary, `onScroll` is *not* guaranteed to fire for the final position unless `scrollEventThrottle` has been set such that `onScroll` fires every frame of scrolling.

There is a performance cost to setting `scrollEventThrottle={16}` that can be reduced by setting it to a larger number. However, this means that `onScroll` will not fire every frame.

#### [`onMomentumScrollEnd`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#onmomentumscrollend)

Fires when the scroll view comes to a stop after gliding. Does not fire at all if the user releases the scroll view while it is stationary such that it does not glide.

#### `onScrollEndDrag`

Fires when the user stops dragging the scroll view - regardless of whether the scroll view is left stationary or begins to glide.

---

Given these differences in behaviour, the best way to keep track of the offset depends upon your precise circumstances. In the most complicated case (you need to support Android and iOS, including handling changes in the `ScrollView`'s frame due to rotation, and you don't want to accept the performance penalty on Android from setting `scrollEventThrottle` to 16), and you need to handle changes to the *content* in the scroll view too, then it's a right damn mess.

The simplest case is if you only need to handle Android; just use `onScroll`:

```js
<ScrollView
  onScroll={event => { 
    this.yOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y
  }}
>
```

To additionally support iOS, *if* you're happy to fire the `onScroll` handler every frame and accept the performance implications of that, and *if* you don't need to handle frame changes, then it's only a little bit more complicated:

```js
<ScrollView
  onScroll={event => { 
    this.yOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y
  }}
  scrollEventThrottle={16}
>
```

To reduce the performance overhead on iOS while still guaranteeing that we record any position that the scroll view settles on, we can increase `scrollEventThrottle` and additionally provide an `onScrollEndDrag` handler:

```js
<ScrollView
  onScroll={event => { 
    this.yOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y
  }}
  onScrollEndDrag={event => { 
    this.yOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y
  }}
  scrollEventThrottle={160}
>
```

But if we want to handle frame changes (e.g. because we allow the device to be rotated, changing the available height for the scroll view's frame) and/or content changes, then we must additionally implement both [`onContentSizeChange`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#oncontentsizechange) and [`onLayout`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#onlayout) to keep track of the height of both the scroll view's frame and its contents, and thereby continually calculate the *maximum* possible offset and infer when the offset has been automatically reduced due to a frame or content size change:

```js
<ScrollView
  onLayout={event => {
    this.frameHeight = event.nativeEvent.layout.height;
    const maxOffset = this.contentHeight - this.frameHeight;
    if (maxOffset < this.yOffset) {
      this.yOffset = maxOffset;
    }
  }}
  onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
    this.contentHeight = contentHeight;
    const maxOffset = this.contentHeight - this.frameHeight;
    if (maxOffset < this.yOffset) {
      this.yOffset = maxOffset;
    }
  }}
  onScroll={event => { 
    this.yOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
  }}
  onScrollEndDrag={event => { 
    this.yOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
  }}
  scrollEventThrottle={160}
>
```

Yeah, it's pretty horrifying. I'm also not 100% certain that it'll always work right in cases where you *simultaneously* change the size of both the frame and content of the scroll view. But it's the best I can come up with, and until [this feature gets added within the framework itself](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2215), I think this is the best that anyone can do.

Comment: Things sure would be a lot easier if one could just access state information about the scrollview, instead of having to manually track its changes. Little crazy there. Great writeup by the way, well explained.

Comment: I've spent hours looking through various react-native tickets and similar SO tickets and this is the most complete solution I've found.  IMO It really disappointing that the corresponding react-native ticket (linked above) was closed and locked as the use case and deficiency here is very obvious.

Answer (score 27):

The above answers tell how to get the position using different API, `onScroll`, `onMomentumScrollEnd` etc; If you want to know the page index, you can calculate it using the offset value.

```
 <ScrollView 
    pagingEnabled={true}
    onMomentumScrollEnd={this._onMomentumScrollEnd}>
    {pages}
 </ScrollView> 

  _onMomentumScrollEnd = ({ nativeEvent }: any) => {
   // the current offset, {x: number, y: number} 
   const position = nativeEvent.contentOffset; 
   // page index 
   const index = Math.round(nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / PAGE_WIDTH);

   if (index !== this.state.currentIndex) {
     // onPageDidChanged
   }
 };
```

[image]

In iOS, the relationship between ScrollView and the visible region is as follow: 
[image: The picture comes from https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/scroll-view/]

ref: https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/scroll-view/

Comment: If you want to get the "index" of the current item, this is the correct answer. You take event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / deviceWidth. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 20):

Brad Oyler's answer is correct. But you will only receive one event. If you need to get constant updates of the scroll position, you should set the `scrollEventThrottle` prop, like so:

```
<ScrollView onScroll={this.handleScroll} scrollEventThrottle={16} >
  <Text>
    Be like water my friend …
  </Text>
</ScrollView>
```

And the event handler:

```
handleScroll: function(event: Object) {
  console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
},
```

Be aware that you might run into performance issues. Adjust the throttle accordingly. 16 gives you the most updates. 0 only one.

Comment: This is incorrect. For one, scrollEvenThrottle only works for iOS and not for android. Second, it only regulates how often you receive onScroll calls. Default is once per frame, not one event. 1 gives you more updates and 16 gives you less. 0 is default. This answer is completely wrong. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrolleventthrottle

Comment: I answered this before Android was supported by React Native, so yes, the answer applys to iOS only. The default value is zero, which results in the scroll event being sent only once each time the view is scrolled.

Comment: What would be the es6 notation for function(event: Object) {} ?

Comment: Just `function(event) { }`.

Comment: @Teodors While this answer doesn't cover Android, the rest of your criticism is completely confused. `scrollEventThrottle={16}` does *not* give you "less" updates; any number in the range 1-16 gives you the maximum possible rate of updates. The default of 0 gives you (on iOS) one event when the user starts scrolling and then no subsequent updates (which is pretty useless and possibly a bug); the default is *not* "once per frame". Besides those two errors in your comment, your other assertions don't contradict anything that the answer says (though you seem to think that they do).

Answer (score 7):

If you wish to simply get the current position (e.g. when some button is pressed) rather than tracking it whenever the user scrolls, then invoking an `onScroll` listener is going to cause performance issues. Currently the most performant way to simply get current scroll position is using [react-native-invoke](https://github.com/wix/react-native-invoke) package. There is an example for this exact thing, but the package does multiple other things.

Read about it here.
https://medium.com/@talkol/invoke-any-native-api-directly-from-pure-javascript-in-react-native-1fb6afcdf57d#.68ls1sopd

Comment: Do you know if a cleaner way (bit less hacky) to request offset exists now, or is this still the best way of doing it you are aware of? 

(I wonder why this answer isn't upvoted as it is the only one that looks to make sense)

Comment: The package is no longer there, did it move somewhere? Github is showing 404.

Answer (score 7):

To get the x/y after scroll ended as the original questions was requesting, the easiest way is probably this:

```
<ScrollView
   horizontal={true}
   pagingEnabled={true}
   onMomentumScrollEnd={(event) => { 
      // scroll animation ended
      console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x);
      console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
   }}>
   ...content
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: -1; `onMomentumScrollEnd` is only triggered if the scroll view has some momentum when the user lets go of it. If they release while the scroll view is not moving, you'll never get any of the momentum events.

Comment: I tested onMomentumScrollEnd and it was imposible for me to not trigger it, I tried scrolling in different ways, I tried releasing the touch when the scroll was in the final position and it also was triggered. So this answer is correct as far as I could test it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be {(e) instead of {( event ) ?

Answer (score 1):

This is how ended up getting the current scroll position live from the view. All I am doing is using the on scroll event listener and the scrollEventThrottle. I am then passing it as an event to handle scroll function I made and updating my props.

```
 export default class Anim extends React.Component {
          constructor(props) {
             super(props);
             this.state = {
               yPos: 0,
             };
           }

        handleScroll(event){
            this.setState({
              yPos : event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y,
            })
        }

        render() {
            return (
          <ScrollView onScroll={this.handleScroll.bind(this)} scrollEventThrottle={16} />
    )
    }
    }
```

Comment: is it good to update state on onScroll considering performance?

Answer (score 0):

As for the page, I'm working on a higher order component that uses basically the above methods to do exactly this. It actually takes just a bit of time when you get down to the subtleties like initial layout and content changes. I won't claim to have done it 'correctly', but in some sense I'd consider the correct answer to use component that does this carefully and consistently.

See: [react-native-paged-scroll-view](https://github.com/rreusser/react-native-paged-scroll-view). Would love feedback, even if it's that I've done it all wrong!

Comment: this is awesome. thank you for making this. i found this very useful right away.

Comment: So glad! Really appreciate the feedback!

Comment: An apologetic -1, since the project openly admits that it is unmaintained and that the component has *"a couple ugly bugs"*.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @MarkAmery. :) Finding the time for open source is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

use of `onScroll` enters infinite loop. `onMomentumScrollEnd` or `onScrollEndDrag` can be used instead

Answer (score -2):

I believe `contentOffset` will give you an object containing the top-left scroll offset:

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#contentoffset

Comment: Isn't this a setter, not a getter?

Comment: -1 this is nonsense; the documentation you've linked to is for a JSX prop, not a JavaScript property, and can only be used to *set* an offset, not to get one.

Answer (score -3):

```html
 <ScrollView style={{ height: hp('70%'), width: '100%' }} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
              ref={myRef}

        // for getting scrollView offset ->

              onScroll={(event => setOffset(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y))}

        // for giving scrollView offset ->

              onContentSizeChange={() =>
                myRef.current.scrollTo({
                  x: 0,
                  y: Offset
                })
              }
            // pagingEnabled={true}
            // scrollEventThrottle={16}
            >
```

<ScrollView

showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}

ref={myRef}

onScroll={(event => setOffset(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y))}

onContentSizeChange={() =>

myRef.current.scrollTo({

```
x: 0,

y: Offset
```

})

}

> 