# React Native Sync Two Scrollviews

Tags: react-native

Is there a way in React Native to sync two or more scrollviews so they follow each other? I've seen some implementations for objective-c but have no idea how to implement that for react native.

Comment: In case someone is still looking for an answer, here is a possible implementation: https://gist.github.com/jevakallio/e95b8ee3c649eb64b2dc768be9375e11

Answer (score 7):

So far the cleanest and less problematic I found was [this](https://snack.expo.io/S1g7axX1G):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native'

function Squares(props) {
    var squares = []
    for (var i = 0; i < props.numRows; i++) {
        squares.push(<View style={{ height: 50, backgroundColor: props.color1 }}><Text>{i}</Text></View>)
        squares.push(<View style={{ height: 50, backgroundColor: props.color2 }}><Text>{i}</Text></View>)
    }
    return squares
}

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.leftIsScrolling = false
        this.rigthIsScrolling = false
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View
                style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-start', backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
                <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#bbb', flexDirection: 'row' }}>

                    <ScrollView
                        scrollEventThrottle={16}
                        ref={scrollView => { this._leftView = scrollView }}
                        onScroll={e => {
                            if (!this.leftIsScrolling) {
                                this.rigthIsScrolling = true
                                var scrollY = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y
                                this._rightView.scrollTo({ y: scrollY })
                            }
                            this.leftIsScrolling = false
                        }}>
                        <Squares numRows={20} color1={"green"} color2={"darkgreen"} />
                    </ScrollView>

                    <ScrollView
                        ref={scrollView => { this._rightView = scrollView }}
                        scrollEventThrottle={16}
                        onScroll={e => {
                            if (!this.rigthIsScrolling) {
                                this.leftIsScrolling = true
                                var scrollY = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y
                                this._leftView.scrollTo({ y: scrollY })
                            }
                            this.rigthIsScrolling = false
                        }}>
                        <Squares numRows={20} color1={"red"} color2={"darkred"} />

                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

I have also tried something along the lines of this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jevakallio/e95b8ee3c649eb64b2dc768be9375e11) but it behaves strangely due to the listener in the scroll position is always affecting the two `ScrollView`s.

For this I was inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41998497/151918) on how to do it in javascript.

Comment: will lead to strange "bounce" on ios. Since `scrollTo` is not a sync move on ios, but set `this.leftIsScrolling = false;` is a sync move.

Answer (score 2):

1. Get the scroll position when one of them is scrolled based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503252/react-native-get-current-scroll-position-of-scrollview)
2. Set the scroll position on the other one with [ScrollView.scrollTo](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.35/docs/scrollview.html#scrollto)

Comment: It works, but not really feasible as the motion is too choppy.

Comment: This will sync the first scroll view to the second, but you wont be able to sync the second to the first as it will create a loop

Answer (score 0):

Use refs:

```
let firstRef: ScrollView | null;
let secondRef: ScrollView | null;

<ScrollView
  ref={ref => (firstRef = ref)}>
...

<ScrollView
  ref={ref => (secondRef = ref)}
  onScroll={e => {
    if(firstRef) {
      firstRef.scrollTo({
      x: e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x,
      y: e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y,
      animated: false
      });
    }
  }  
  >
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView>
  <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled={true}>
  </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

video ref. from google to explain how it works

[image]

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

All these answers are a bit buggy and fail to synchronize ScrollViews with different orientations or sizes / lengths. Here is a short 3 minute video I found that uses a [cleaner, far more reliant approach](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9tE32G7WGj4)