# Scroll position should be placed in where last time it was in react native

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, infinite-scroll, react-native-flatlist

The biggest problem of `StackNavigator` is that components won't be unmounted, i.e., `componentWillUnmount()` won't be invoked.

But I need this component stage to unbind event, or to do other things. And that's why I started using `DrawerNavigator`.

But this brings another issue which `StackNavigator` would solve automatically.

I have a component which loads data from the server. In this component, I just show the summery, and whenever a user clicks on that, another component appears to show details. That means there are two components (screen). So, a user navigates to detail screen, (`AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: action.route}), currentState);`) and then he/she pressed (hardware) back button, as I override the default behavior of this event (close the app), he/she will navigate to list screen. Now, the problem is, say he/she was in 15th data, now when he/she navigated from detail screen, the scrollbar is in first data! Had I used `StackNavigator`, the scrollbar would have been in 15th data.

I implemented this using `ScrollView`, and `FlatList`. Used `onMomentumScrollEnd` props to get more data from the server.

So, how can I solve this, the scrollbar should be placed where it was last time, and at the same time get the feature of `componetWillUnmount`?

Comment: save that scroll position and then use ListView.scrollTo and get last stored position form your cache

Comment: Would you please tell me how to get current scroll position?

Comment: calculated height, and used `this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset({offset: value})` to scroll to a position.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503252/get-current-scroll-position-of-scrollview-in-react-native?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa check this answer