# Flatlist scroll position onScroll

Tags: react-native

I am building a header that animates/hides as the user scrolls down a Flatlist.
Is there any way to find out the scroll position of the Flatlist in pixels?

I'm using react native 0.59.8.
I've tried using onScroll hoping it passes a value to the callback - it doesn't.
I've also tried onScrollBeginDrag, onScrollEndDrag and onMomentumScrollEnd.. None of them provide information of the current scroll position.

```
onSroll={(info)=>{console.log(info)}
```

I would expect to get some information about the scroll, but none is passed.

Comment: I don't quite get your issue, in my test it works as expected.
I've created a short fiddle for getting the scroll value from the onScroll Event, maybe you can track down your issue like this.
Here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/s7b5p0tx/1/

The scroll position will be displayed in console.

Comment: @NickG I'm referring to React Native, not React js (web).

Comment: oh well, my bad

Comment: sorry to point out the obvious, but your code above is `onSroll` not `onScroll`

Comment: @MikeM Whoops. Typing too fast. Thanks! And thanks to all the answers. I don't have enough cred to upvote.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
<FlatList onScroll={this.handleScrollView} />
```

e.g.

```
handleScrollView: function(event: Object) {
 this.setState({ scrollPosition: event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its working

```
     onScroll={(r) => console.log(r.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y)}
```

post your code here if you want to find bug

Answer (score 0):

A `Flatlist`, as said in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#props), has all the props of a `ScrollView`, so as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503252/get-current-scroll-position-of-scrollview-in-react-native),

Add a handler to your FlatList:

```
<FlatList onScroll={this.handleScroll} />
```

And then:

```
handleScroll: function(event) {
   console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
},
```