# react-native : change view corresponding to scroll position

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am using `Animation.view` to change the `height` and the `background` of the `header`.

I set my `height` and the `background` settings  like this:

```
const HeaderHeight = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange:[0, Header_Max_Height - Header_Min_Height],
      outputRange:[Header_Max_Height, Header_Min_Height],
      extrapolate:'clamp'
    })

const AnimateHeaderBackgroundColor = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
        inputRange: [ 0, ( Header_Max_Height - Header_Min_Height )  ],
        outputRange: [ '#009688', '#00BCD4' ],
        extrapolate: 'clamp'
    })
```

This is my animated.view.

```
<Animated.View style={{width:'100%', height: HeaderHeight, backgroundColor:AnimateHeaderBackgroundColor}}></Animated.View>
```

Everything works well.

**My question** is there a way I could change the view like the `height` and the `backgroundcolor`?

For example, say I have two views:

```
//view1
<View style={{width:'100%',height:100, backgroundColor:'red'}}>
 <Text>View1</Text>
</View>

//view2
<View style={{width:'100%',height:100, backgroundColor:'blue'}}>
  <Text>View2</Text>
</View>
```

I want the `view1` to show by default and show `view2` as I scroll to the top of the screen. Placing the `View` in the `outputRange` would make this possible?

Comment: you want to show `view2` in place of `view1`when scrolling downwards with some animation??

Comment: @AnkitMakwana just like the animation header. Instead of changing colors I want to swipe views.

Comment: when swiping the views, what is the animation? changing the height? or opacity?

Comment: @nikolai-serg not quite sure what u mean. I want to change the view as I scroll.

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to put `view1` in a `scrollView`, and change `view1` to `view2` when you scroll to a particular position?

Comment: @Andus Yes exactly thats right. Thanks for understading.

Comment: Since you are asking an animation related question, do you mean you want to animate the process above? What will be the animation you want (e.g. fadein / fadeout)?

Comment: @andus just like the color change from black to white. Is it possible to animate veiw1 -> View2?

Comment: @kirimi please check my answer down there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess there's no direct way in RN if you want to animated a change of view, however, in your case I can think of a little trick using the mix of `opacity`, `position: absolute` and `interpolate()`, here is a minimal example which you can directly copy and paste to test it:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Animated, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

class AnimationExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      showBlueView: false,
      animatedOpacityValue: new Animated.Value(0),
    }
  }

  handleScroll = (event) => {
    const { animatedOpacityValue, showBlueView } = this.state;
    const scrollPosition = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;

    if (scrollPosition > 100 && !showBlueView) {
      Animated.timing(animatedOpacityValue, {
        toValue: 1,
      }).start(() => this.setState({ showBlueView: true }))
    }

    if (scrollPosition < 100 && showBlueView) {
      Animated.timing(animatedOpacityValue, {
        toValue: 0,
      }).start(() => this.setState({ showBlueView: false }))
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { animatedOpacityValue } = this.state;
    return (
      <ScrollView
        style={styles.scrollView}
        onScroll={this.handleScroll}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
      >
        <View style={styles.green} />
        <View style={styles.animatedViewsPositioner}>
          <Animated.View
            style={{
              ...styles.red,
              opacity: animatedOpacityValue.interpolate({
                inputRange: [0, 1],
                outputRange: [1, 0],
              }),
            }}
          />
          <Animated.View
            style={{
              ...styles.blue,
              opacity: animatedOpacityValue.interpolate({
                inputRange: [0, 1],
                outputRange: [0, 1],
              }),
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  green: {
    height: 600,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
  red: {
    height: 300,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  blue: {
    position: 'absolute',
    height: 300,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
  animatedViewsPositioner: {
    position: 'relative',
  },
})
```

In the example above, I first access the scroll position by applying a `handleScroll` function to the `scrollView`. Make sure you have `scrollEventThrottle` set to 16 to ensure the function is triggered every second, but beware of possible performance issue caused by that (if you care, you might take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503252/get-current-scroll-position-of-scrollview-in-react-native) for more info).

To achieve a view change triggered when user scroll to certain position (which is actually not, but it looks like that), I use a `view` to wrap both red and blue views, the red one is default with `opacity: 1`, while the blue one with default `opacity: 0`, sitting on top of the red one.

I hide the red view and show the blue one by animating their `opacity` using `interpolate()`. With the help of that, both opacity values are controlled by one animatedValue `animatedOpacityValue` put in the state. I added a state `showBlueView` to optimise the performance by avoid constantly setting states triggered by onScroll.

---

Here's an update to add `touchableOpacities` on both views, simply achieve by hiding the blue view when it's unused.

First, add a log function:

```
log = (stringToPrint) => () => {
  console.log(stringToPrint)
}
```

Next, change the `scrollView` like this by adding two `touchableOpacity`

```
<ScrollView
  style={styles.scrollView}
  onScroll={this.handleScroll}
  scrollEventThrottle={16}
>
  <View style={styles.green} />
  <View style={styles.animatedViewsPositioner}>
    <Animated.View
      style={{
        ...styles.red,
        opacity: animatedOpacityValue.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: [1, 0],
        }),
      }}
    >
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'black', width: 80, height: 30 }}
        onPress={this.log('click on red')}
      />
    </Animated.View>
    {showBlueView && (
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          ...styles.blue,
          opacity: animatedOpacityValue.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, 1],
          }),
        }}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ backgroundColor: 'black', width: 80, height: 30 }}
          onPress={this.log('click on blue')}
        />
      </Animated.View>
    )}
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Note that I added `showBlueView &&` to hide the blue view when its opacity is 0, so that it will not block any click event applied to the red view (even though the blue view is hidden, it is actually on top of the red view with `opacity: 0`).

Comment: thanks very much for the answer. I am trying it out. I placed `TouchableOpacity` inside the `Animated.View` but won't work. Do you know how to handle `TouchableOpacity` inside `Animated.View`?

Comment: What do you mean won't work? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry if I wasn't clear. I like your idea and it works well. But the reason I am trying to swipe `views ` is to place `buttons` and `touchableOpacity` inside the `animated.view`. But `onPress` will not work if I place a `button` or `touchableOpacity` inside your code  `Animated.View`

Comment: This is because you are actually having the blue view covering you red view, are you putting a `touchableOpacity` on the red view?

Comment: Actually I was planning to have `touchableOpacity` in both views. Is it possible to have `touchableOpacity` in both view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205643/discussion-between-andus-and-kirimi).

Answer (score 3):

@Andus 's ans with `Animated.event`

The idea is to get the latest scrollY then wrap it to view's opacity. The example input range of blue target is 0-50 and got opacity 1 to 0. That means it would fade out when scrolling down the first 50 px.

The red one is the reverse one with input range 0-200 and out to opacity 0 to 1.(fade in)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Animated, View, ScrollView, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

export default class AnimationExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      scrollY: new Animated.Value(0)
    }
  }

  render() {
  const {scrollY} = this.state;
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <ScrollView
        style={styles.scrollView}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: this.state.scrollY}}}]
        )}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
      >
        <View style={styles.animatedViewsPositioner}>
          <Animated.View
            style={[styles.box, styles.target, {
             opacity: scrollY.interpolate({
                inputRange: [0, 50],
                outputRange: [1, 0],
              }),
            }]}
          />
          <Animated.View
           style={[styles.box, styles.origin, {
             opacity: scrollY.interpolate({
                inputRange: [0, 200],
                outputRange: [0, 1],
              }),
            }]}
          />
        </View>

      </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  box: {
    height: 1000,
    width: '100%',
    position: 'absolute'
  },
  origin: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    zIndex: 1
  },
  target: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    zIndex: 2
  },
  animatedViewsPositioner: {
    position: 'relative',
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    height: 10000
  },
})
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `ScrollView` in displaying the `View`, I believe you can use the `onScroll` callback to get the position of your screen inside the `ScrollView` and change the height and color dynamically when your user scroll to the top.

```
<ScrollView onScroll={this.handleScroll} />
```

And getting the position,

```
handleScroll: function(event: Object) {
  console.log(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y);
},
```

Reference: [Get current scroll position of ScrollView in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503252/get-current-scroll-position-of-scrollview-in-react-native)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I know I could dynamically change the color or the height. But this is not what I am trying to achieve.